# jQuery Collapse when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need help here... I have a menu that is collapsible, when the page starts I want to stay open but when scroll down I want to be collapsed... Is there any option for that?

```
$('#slide-button').click(function(){
    $('#menu-list').animate({width: 'toggle'},500);
    $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

Here is my site http://astritbublaku.com/demos/dukagjini/

Comment: could you be a bit more specific, I can't find the collapsible menu..

Comment: Your menu structure looks good when you scroll down. Why you need to collapse the top menu during scroll down?

Comment: yes i am sorry... if u open the site, u will see the topmenu open (explore,blog etc..),and it collapses only when click...but i also want when i scroll down to the page i want to collapse that menu...i dont know if that is possible

Comment: @AstritBublaku You can do that with triggering click event on scroll. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535541/jquery-collapse-when-scroll/23535824#23535824)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
       $('#menu-list').animate({"width": minWidth },500);
       $(this).addClass('inactive');
      }
    else
     {
        $('#menu-list').animate({"width": maxWidth },500);
        $(this).removeleClass('inactive');
       }
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much, it collapses when scroll, but it opens and closes whenever i scroll, so i scroll only one time it opens, second closes...what i want is when scroll to be closed,and if anyone wants to open to do that with the button that has it...

Comment: try using a definite width instead of 'toggle':

maxWidth and minWidth.

See the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start as opened
    $(".book-toggle").trigger("click");

    // When scrolled, if collapsible is opened, close it
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Check if it is already closed. It has class 'inactive' when it is open
        if ($(".book-box").hasClass("inactive") == false) {
            $(".book-toggle").trigger("click");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tesekkur Ederim Huseyin Kardes :)... Book Toggle is fine, i just needed the top menu...t's a stupid thing to do, but my client wants in that way.. thanks